# absolute positioning and scrollable DIV

Tags: css

I have this tricky CSS problem: I have this HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>

    <div id="scroll">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque faucibus volutpat turpis at iaculis. Proin at nisl leo. Morbi nec blandit leo? Pellentesque interdum nunc sed nisl rhoncus gravida. Nunc sollicitudin, mi sit amet porta mollis, metus erat ornare odio, eu accumsan mauris diam nec augue. Ut tincidunt dui at lorem consequat vitae consectetur sapien pharetra. Suspendisse potenti. Donec turpis enim, varius accumsan congue vitae, rhoncus ut justo. Curabitur tristique lobortis eros ut pharetra. Maecenas non condimentum justo. Integer tincidunt; velit quis auctor varius, magna lorem pharetra urna, eget pellentesque leo nibh at mi. Ut pretium bibendum dui vel venenatis. Proin vel sem vitae lacus tincidunt bibendum. Pellentesque blandit mauris sit amet mauris sollicitudin pretium. In molestie condimentum nisi placerat consequat.
    </div>

    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 47px;
}

#scroll {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10000px;
}

div.left, div.right {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 24px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
}

div.left {
    left: 0;
}

div.right {
    right: 0;
}
```

And the visual result is this:
[image]

For some reason, the `div.right` is moving when I scroll the `#scroll`. I want it to always float at the boundary of `#wrapper`.

This is what I get right now:
[image]

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fYH/

Thank you

**Edit**

Just because it wasn't obvious, it must work on mobile devices.

Comment: I know that I could put the div.right in the #scroll but is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

You have to know the difference between `position: absolute` and `position: fixed`.

The first one means: place the element in absolute position within relative element and keep in in that place (relatively).

The second: place the element in absolute position within **window** (frame) and keep it there no matter what happens.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5fYH/1/

Comment: Thank you, yeah I was avoiding fixed positioning as my `DIV` shouldn't go outside `#wrapper`. In the real template, `#wrapper` is a `col span_X` container resized with Twitter Bootstrap and it's not full screen width.

Comment: what do you do if the "fixed" elements  don't need to be relative to the viewport..but instead to the "wrapper"?

Comment: how do you do it if you can't use fixed?
https://jsfiddle.net/carinlynchin/z6sophn0/4/

Comment: if i use static it sticks..but I don't understand why it has to be static... why doesn't it stick to its parent that is relative?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with how overflow-x changes the wrapper div width.

The solution I found was:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5jWpG/

1. wrapping the whole thing with a new div with the id wrapper-container
2. then adding the following CSS code:

   ```
   #wrapper-container {
       position: relative;
   }

   #wrapper {
       position: static; /* or remove position relative from your code */
   }

   div.left, div.right {
       bottom: 16px; 
       height: auto; /* or remove height: 100% from your code */
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does work in my browser but it doesn't on my Android Phone. I will edit my original question as I thought the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` was obvious enough.